# Error message when running npreg

Tags: r

I'm working the npreg example in the R np package documentation (by T. Hayfield, J. Racine), section 3.1 Univariate Regression.

```
library("np")
data("cps71")
model.par = lm(logwage~age + I(age^2),data=cps71)
summary(model.par)
#
attach(cps71)
bw = npregbw(logwage~age) # thislne not in example 3.1
model.np = npreg(logwage~age,regtype="ll", bwmethod="cv.aic",gradients="TRUE",        
+ data=cps71)
```

This copied directly from the example, but the npreg call results in error message

```
 *Rerun with Debug
 Error in npreg.rbandwidth(txdat = txdat, tydat = tydat, bws = bws, ...) : 
  NAs in foreign function call (arg 15)   
In addition: Warning message:
In npreg.rbandwidth(txdat = txdat, tydat = tydat, bws = bws, ...) :
  NAs introduced by coercion*
```

The npreg R documentation indicates the first argument should be BW specificaion. I tried setting bws=1

```
model.np = npreg(bws=1,logwage~age,regtype="ll", 
 + bwmethod="cv.aic",gradients="TRUE", data=cps71)
```

which gives the following error

```
*Error in toFrame(xdat) : 
  xdat must be a data frame, matrix, vector, or factor*
```

First time working with density estimation in R. Please suggest how to resolve these errors.